# Crystal Report to Print Envelope Labels

Tags: crystal-reports

Anybody ever tried to use crystal reports to generate envelope labels? The requirement is to print 8 labels (2 columns, 4 rows) on a letter size paper. How can I control the repeat flow to meet such requirement?

Thanks

Hardy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the Details section to have multiple columns.  Size the columns and spacing between them to accommodate the label.